# How create button using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I want create any instance from GAC dlls , but don't know how load ?

```
Assembly asemb = Assembly.LoadFile(dllName);
try
{
    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(asemb.GetType(type));
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

I try this code but it's not work

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: What's wrong with `new Button()` ?

Comment: I getting Exception **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: I need create class instance from string name

Comment: What are `dllName` and `type` values?

Comment: dllName = "System.Windows.Forms"; type = "Button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
var type     = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button");
var button   = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

To get full assembly name from .dll file:

```
var assemblyFileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll";
var assembly         = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFileName);
var assemblyName     = assembly.GetName().ToString();
```

Comment: I want load DLL **dynamicly** , not only for controls .... how get dll Version , Culture and PublicKeyToken by DLL name ?